# How to invalidate array of sluges in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Since 12.1.0 it is possible the On-demand Revalidation.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Sending array of programIds, how can I invalidate array of slugs? I tried this:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
    if (req.query.secret !== process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
    }

    try {
        const programIds: String[] = req.query.programId
        programIds.map((programId) =>
            await res.unstable_revalidate(`/hu/buyTicket/${programId}`)
        )
        
        return res.json({ revalidated: true })
    } catch (err) {
        // If there was an error, Next.js will continue
        // to show the last successfully generated page
        return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix it for you, but just looking at the error message, your problem is that your .map() is not async. Change is to:
programIds.map(async (programId) => ... )

Comment: @Julius htanks, that was the problem :)

Comment: Cool, I'll make an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` does not respect `await` even if you use `async`. In your situation, you will receive a response before revalidation is completed, which is **incorrect behavior**.

The correct method should include the usage of `Promise.all` so that `res.json` is called only after all the revalidations are completed, and `try/catch` block can catch error correctly.

```
  await Promise.all(programIds.map(async (programId) =>
        await res.unstable_revalidate(`/hu/buyTicket/${programId}`)
  ))
```